# Combining data in SQL Union syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I'm doing a SQL Union syntax and I wanted to have a result like this:

```
+---------------+-----+---------+
|trkBusinessUnit| New | Pending |
+---------------+-----+---------+
|      AIIB         2      0    |
| Credit Control    1      3    |
|  Direct Center    1      2    |
| Financial Ins     1      1    |
| Motor Acclaim     1      0    |
+-------------------------------+
```

from my code:

```
SELECT trkBusinessUnit, Count(*) as New,0 as Pending
FROM tblDTPTracker
WHERE trkStatus = 'New'
GROUP BY trkBusinessUnit

UNION

SELECT trkBusinessUnit,0 as New,Count(*) as Pending
FROM tblDTPTracker
WHERE trkStatus = 'Pending'
GROUP BY trkBusinessUnit
```

but then the current output is:

```
+---------------+-----+---------+
|trkBusinessUnit| New | Pending |
+---------------+-----+---------+
|      AIIB         2      0    |
| Credit Control    1      0    |
| Credit Control    0      3    |
|  Direct Center    1      0    |
|  Direct Center    0      2    |
| Financial Ins     1      0    |
| Financial Ins     0      1    |
| Motor Acclaim     1      0    |
+-------------------------------+
```

Am I missing out something or doing something wrong? Kindly advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (or has been) some syntax issues in the previous answers, but the intent of both earlier answers is correct, you need to use a `GROUP BY` query and NOT use `UNION` - which simply does not do what you were hoping/expecting.

UNION or UNION ALL work ROW by ROW, and absolutely do NOT merge by COLUMN

So, the MySQL syntax for the group by based query could be any of these:

**COUNT() using an implicit NULL**

```
SELECT 
       trkBusinessUnit
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN trkStatus = 'New'     THEN 1 END) as New 
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN trkStatus = 'Pending' THEN 1 END) as Pending
FROM tblDTPTracker
GROUP BY trkBusinessUnit
;
```

**COUNT() using explicit NULL**

```
SELECT 
       trkBusinessUnit
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN trkStatus = 'New'     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as New 
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN trkStatus = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Pending
FROM tblDTPTracker
GROUP BY trkBusinessUnit
;
```

**SUM() as an alternative to counting:**

```
select
       trkBusinessUnit
     , sum(case when trkStatus = 'New'     then 1 else 0 end) as New
     , sum(case when trkStatus = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) as Pending
from tblDTPTracker
where trkStatus in ('Pending', 'New')
group by trkBusinessUnit
;
```

Apologies to both Marc Gravell & Daniel Gadawski who preceded this answer; this answer is a derivative of yours.

<kbd>[See this SQLFiddle demo of these queries](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72d19/6)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you don't have to use an union.

Try:

```
SELECT 
    trkBusinessUnit, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN trkStatus = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as New, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN trkStatus = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as Pending
FROM tblDTPTracker
GROUP BY trkBusinessUnit
```

Comment: Hi Daniel thank you for your answer; however, I have an error which says 'missing operator in query expression 'count(case when trkStatus = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)'. How do we deal with this? Thanks

Comment: I think your query is escaped incorrectly. Can you show the code where you invoke this query?

Comment: The "missing operator" is due to [mysql's `case` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) - it simply needs to end with `end case` rather than just `end`.

Comment: I just copied your code directly into a blank query. What am I doing wrong? apologies I'm just new in MySQL.

Comment: @DanielGadawski Used_By_Already tells me I am wrong there; you might want to revert that! Sorry

Comment: :) I'm afraid so. no need to `end case`

Answer (score 0):

Union appends rows vertically (noting that `UNION` also takes only the distinct rows; `UNION ALL` takes all rows). What you want is either a `full outer join` of two sub-queries, or a more complicated `select`. I'd go with the latter!

```
select tblDTPTracker,
       sum(case trkStatus when 'New' then 1 else 0 end) as New,
       sum(case trkStatus when 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) as Pending
from tblDTPTracker
where trkStatus in ('Pending', 'New')
group by tblDTPTracker
```

The full outer join approach would be something like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(x.trkBusinessUnit, y.trkBusinessUnit) as trkBusinessUnit,
       ISNULL(x.New, 0) as New,
       ISNULL(y.Pending, 0) as Pending
FROM (
    SELECT trkBusinessUnit, Count(1) as New
    FROM tblDTPTracker
    WHERE trkStatus = 'New'
    GROUP BY trkBusinessUnit) x
FULL OUTER JOIN (        
    SELECT trkBusinessUnit, Count(1) as Pending
    FROM tblDTPTracker
    WHERE trkStatus = 'Pending'
    GROUP BY trkBusinessUnit) y on y.trkBusinessUnit = x.trkBusinessUnit
```

Comment: Hi Marc thank you for your answer; however, I have an error which says 'missing operator in query expression 'sum(case trkStatus when 'New' then 1 else 0 end)'. How can we make amendments on this? Thanks

Comment: A case expression, which is what is used above, does not require `case end` which is for case statements. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: Hi Mark, I did what you say but still the same. though it will highligh "trkStatus" on the first sum syntax.

Comment: @MarcGravell what are those x and y trkBusinessUnit?

Comment: @CaptainBadass named sub-queries; I can't say for sure whether that'll work "as is" on mysql - the exact flavor of sql changes between databases

Comment: @MarcGravell MySQL does require aliases for subqueries like TSQL, but you also need to drop the square brackets which MySQL does not like. It prefers backticks e.g. [New] would be ` New ` without the spaces (would you believe it backticks are used by SO for formatting)